# Access.Application.CurrentDb is Nothing?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm at a loss to explain this one:

I am getting an error:

> Error "91" (Object or With block not set)

on the second line below:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM employees")
```

The following also causes it:

```
`Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("employees")`
```

Executing `?CurrentDb.Name` alone in the immediate window causes the error as well.

Now, clearly the database is open since I'm editing the form within it, so what can cause this error here?

Comment: What's between the parens for OpenRecordset?

Comment: Patrick is on the right track. Can you provide the entire line of code. I think it is probably related to the OpenRecordset failing.

You could also test in the command window to confirm what you think is happening is really happening
?Access.Application.currentdb is nothing

Comment: Is this code in a module, or on a form or other? Are you working with an ADP project, or plain vanilla Access database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are working with an ADP project, you should use CurrentProject instead of CurrentDB.

Comment: Not only will you need to use `CurrentProject` with an ADP, but you'll need to use the entire ADODB module to interact with the database.  A starting point: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281998.

Answer (score 3):

you should assign your .openRecordset method to a dao.recordset object or a generic object ('late binding' technique). try something like this:

```
dim rs as dao.recordset
set rs = currentDb.openRecordset(your SELECT instruction,...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a database object and using that instead of the CurrentDb reference.  For example:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Employees")
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason l suspect the code will not work is that according to M/Soft [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221178%28office.11%29.aspx) 'CurrentDb' is a method which will return an 'object variable of type **Database**'.  So the code shown by Forester93 should work.  Its what l would use and have been using for many years now.